# How to set up the configuration file in camera calibration source code from OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, configuration-files, camera-calibration

Im using the camera calibration source code from OpenCV in this link http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

In the configuration file may choose to use camera as an input, a video file or an image list.I would like to use the last option . So I tried to create a configuration file where I enumerate the images to use.

Here’s my configuration file .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
-<opencv_storage>    
<images> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img1.png C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img2.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\im3.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img4.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img5.png C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img6.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img7.png C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img8.png  </images>
</opencv_storage>
```

So far I understand the config file in Visual Studio 2012 need to be specified with Right click on Project-> Properties-> Configuration->Configuration Properties, Debugging then Command Argument where I put the name of the config file. Then I placed the the config.xml file the project source file in Visual Studio 2012. But when run the code I code this error come in command window:

```
Could not open the configuration file:config.xml
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that "-" before  the problem? I am pretty sure that shouldn't be there

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I think the file should be: (remove the "-" character, but I am not sure if it was that the source of the error

<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<opencv_storage>    
<images> C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img1.png C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img2.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\im3.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img4.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img5.png C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img6.png  C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img7.png C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Images\img8.png  </images>
</opencv_storage>